# How to configure IIS to set the specified owner for new log files?

Tags: iis

Good day!

Now IIS creates new log files with unknown for me users, and I must to change owner, when I try to read new log file. How can I specify some user, for new log files? Or what else can I do?

Comment: Have you searched for "windows file permissions inheritance"?

Comment: Can you post more details information about your requirement? what log file does iis create? What do you want to change the owner to?